# Server records wrong IP (proxy/firewall/load balancer)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, vmware-vsphere

I have a VDS server running Windows Server Web 2008 and plesk 10 installed. I figured out I'm getting not the visitor IP but a fixed IP (178.18.198.2) at my website codes asp.net/php. I also get this IP in IIS log files. Can anybody explain what is happening?

My server ips are 178.18.198.90 - 178.18.198.94 and my subnet mask is 178.18.198.1. One of the websites running on this server is [innovacube.com](https://innovacube.com/)

Question on Stack Overflow about same problem [Cannot get user IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014816/cannot-get-user-ip-address-proxy-firewall-load-balancer)

**UPDATE** Company suggested me to use HTTP_CLIENT_IP header instead of REMOTE_ADDR, also for the IIS logs I have to use [XCLIENT.DLL for Microsoft Internet Information Services](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118087)  ISAPI filter.

[How to Make the Web Server Logs Display the Real IP Address of the Client as the Source IP Address for All HTTP Requests?](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX110389)

And here is another useful article: [HOWTO: ISAPI Filter which Logs original Client IP for Load Balanced IIS Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-isapi-filter-which-logs-original-client-ip-for-load-balanced-iis-servers)

Comment: and what exactly is 178.18.198.2?

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is 178.18.198.1's host name is 198-1.vargonen.net but 178.18.198.2 has no host name.

Comment: It has 00-D0-68-11-C2-7C MAC address which seems to be a IWILL CORPORATION product. It could be a Server, Workstation or Security Appliance

Comment: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118087 not found

Comment: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX110389 not found

Answer (score 3):

178.18.198.2 is apparently a proxy and/or firewall that all your incoming requests are coming through. When I visit http://innovacube.com/key.aspx, I do see *my* IP address in the HTTP_CLIENT_IP field, which is why I suspect that your mystery .2 appliance is indeed a proxy, and apparently a transparent one, as an `nslookup` on innovacube.com returns 178.18.198.90.

In your code, you should use this field to determine your visitors' IP addresses, as well as update your logs to log this header (sorry, don't know how to do this for IIS). But beware that what works on these servers likely will not work in another environment/on another network.

Comment: Yes I have to use this header. Also I have to install an ISAPI filter: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118087 I'll post here if the problem is solved or not. Thanks.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118087 not found

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your router/default gateway is natting incoming requests so that your server logs fill with that devices ip?

Comment: I don't think so. Even Google sees this ip when it visits my log page: http://innovacube.com/key.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try get this

```
context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]
```

in my case it works.

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR works but It's too hard to change all wordpress sites for this situation.